# When $\frac{-1436+y\pm \sqrt{(1436-y)^2 - 4\cdot480547}}{-2}$ is integer

Tags: factoring

While working on my [algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118529/integer-factorization-possible-) I came to this problem:

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b-a+y \pm \sqrt{(b + a-y)^2 - 4c}}{-2}$$
$$x_1 = \frac{c}{x_2}$$

- $a,b,c$ are positive known integers
- $y$ is positive integer

How can I find for what values of $y$, $x_{1,2}$ are positive integers? In the title I gave an example for such numbers, the solutions is $x_{1,2} = 661,727$, $y = 56$